# I want the output to be like {'Red':1,'Blue':2,'Green':3} .I'm only getting {'Green':3}

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary

```
list_color=['Red','Blue','Green']

for i ,b in enumerate(list_color,1):

    if i<=2:
        dict ={b:i}

    else:
        break

    i+=1

print(dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Green':3}
```

Answer (score 2):

You told interpreter to reassign name `dict` with new value, not to update a dict.

```
dict = {b:i}  # we talk about this line
```

For creating objects based on another iterable, *comprehensions* are typical way to go, in this case a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
colors = ['Red','Blue','Green']
d = {color: idx for idx, color in enumerate(colors, 1)}
# {'Blue': 2, 'Green': 3, 'Red': 1}
```

Order is not kept, because dictionaries are unordered data structure.

Also, try to avoid naming your objects based on builtins, when `dict` name is used, it shadows [`dict` builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have so many statements in the for loop, so I'm giving a simple example:

```
list_color=['Red','Blue','Green']
dict={}
for i ,b in enumerate(list_color,1):
    dict[b] = i

print(dict)
```

Please note, how I define dict to be an empty dictionary before the loop. The other thing I changed is the way you assign values to the dictionary. You were overwriting the complete content of the dictionary with each assignment. I'm showing now how to add values to the dictionary.

I recommend a site like http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html which allows to to visualize the execution of the code. Then you can see what's going on/wrong/not according to your expectations.